# How can I change the theme of my Hyper Terminal (downloaded from hyper.is)?

Tags: terminal, hyper

If you have any experience with the downloadable software "Hyper" which is basically just a terminal, then you might be able to help me. I can't change the theme, its look. I am on the newest version of MacOS. I tried opening the file hyper.js but my computer can't find it. "~/Library/Application Support/Hyper/.hyper.js" marks an error. What can I do to change the theme?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to go up to the Hyper (On the top bar next to the "apple" logo on my mac), then click on "Preferences". That opens a JavaScript file that contains values such as colors for different parts of the "Hyper" program. Head to "foregroundColor" and you can change the font color. I chose '#27fe16' so that it looks like the traditional cool terminal.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did:

1. Open Hyper Terminal.
2. Go to Menu->Edit->Preferences or press Ctrl + ,
3. .hyper file will be opened for clarification.
4. Under the modules.exports section, navigate to config section.
5. Find plugins: ["hyper-material-theme", "verminal"],
6. Remove the Plugin/Theme and save and exit.
7. You will see a notification "Hyper Configuration reloaded!"
8. Example: [] for default theme.

Answer (score 3):

## To install new themes on Hyper:

1. Go to https://hyper.is/themes
2. Find the theme you want from that website
3. take note of the name of the theme
4. go to hyper cmd line and type `hyper i <name of theme>`. E.g `hyper i hyper-material-theme` for installing hyper-material-theme

## To uninstall Theme

do `hyper uninstall <name of theme>`. E.g. E.g `hyper uninstall hyper-material-theme` for uninstalling hyper-material-theme

## To see what themes you have:

1. Open hyper
2. Press Ctrl + ,
3. See module.exports.plugins. It is an array of themes you have downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is similar on both Windows as well as MacOS.
On Windows, This is what I did:

1. Open Hyper Terminal
2. Go to Menu->Edit->Preferences or press Ctrl + ,
   [Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZxUb.png)
3. .hyper file will be opened for clarification
4. Under the **modules.exports** section, navigate to **config section**.
5. There you will find all font related options, i.e Size, Color, Background Color,
   Border Color etc.
   [Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBi10.png)
6. Select the colors combination you want in Hex format.
7. **Save** file and exit.