# How to reset theme to default in hyper terminal

Tags: terminal, hyperterm

I've installed a new theme in hyper and now it looks like this. What can I do to fix it? [hyper_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQOWb.png)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the Github](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/2211), try deleting your config file at `~/Library/Application Support/Hyper/.hyper.js`. This should reset your customizations (including the theme).

If you want to customize the theme yourself, check out the question [How can I change the theme of my Hyper Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668216/how-can-i-change-the-theme-of-my-hyper-terminal-downloaded-from-hyper-is)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just run `hyper uninstall <theme-name>` in the hyper app.